# XPage: Tablesorter for Datatable

Tags: jquery, xpages, lotus-notes, tablesorter

i was trying to implement a [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to one of my datatable (XPages).
So i have addres jquery-1.11.1.js and the jquery.tablesorter.min.js

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:this.resources>
<xp:script src="/jquery-1.11.1.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
<xp:script src="/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:scriptBlock>

<xp:this.value><![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#dataTable1").tablesorter(); 
} 
); 

    ]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>

<xp:dataTable id="dataTable1" rows="30" styleClass="tablesorter">
    <xp:column id="column1">
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedFieldName"><xp:this.value>  
<![CDATA[#  {javascript:testArray[0]}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
        <xp:this.facets>
<xp:label value="Name" id="label1" xp:key="header"></xp:label></xp:this.facets> 
</xp:column>
<xp:column id="column2">
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedFieldAdress"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[# 
{javascript:testArray[1]}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
<xp:this.facets>
<xp:label value="Adress" id="label2" xp:key="header"></xp:label></xp:this.facets> 
</xp:column>
</xp:dataTable>

</xp:view>
```

Can you tell me, why its not working?

Regards

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the javascript console? I believe that tablesorter v2.0.5b from tablesorter.com still uses `$.browser` so this would cause some problems with jQuery v1.11.1. You might want to check out my [branch of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the produced HTML source you will find out that your data table doesn't have the id "dataTable1" as XSP computes those ids at runtime. Your datatable has a class though, so you can use this to init your jQuery script like this:

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
```

Another option is to compute the id within the script (this works as long your script resides in the xp:scriptBlock tag and not in an external library), like this:

```
var dataTable = dojo.byId("#{id:dataTable1}"); // get the element by it's real id
var tableId = dataTable.id;
$("#"+tableId).tablesorter();
```

This may not function though because jQuery doesn't like colons in the id's name, so you want to have a look at this workaround: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=x-jquery-selector-for-xpages

Comment: At the top of the page for [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) it states: "To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^\`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes.